# programmatically create block to inject on checkout page in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, php-5.4

In checkout page on Billing Section If user enter wrong address details (ex: address validation) I want inject block.

when I put my code in `indexAction` it's working. but `saveBillingAction` not working. Any Idea?

```
 public function indexAction()
    {
..............
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
            'my_block_name_here',
            array('template' => 'activecodeline/developer.phtml')
        );

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->append($block);
..............
     }
```

**it's working.**

```
    public function saveBillingAction()
        {

            if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
                return;
            }
            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
                $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing_address_id', false);

                if (!$customerAddressId) {
                    $continue = $this->ValidateAddress($data['city'], $data['stateOrProvince'],$data['postalCode'],$data['countryCode']);
                    if (!$continue) {

             $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                       'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
                      'my_block_name_here',
                      array('template' => 'activecodeline/developer.phtml')
                      );

                  $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->append($block);                            

                        return;
                    }
                }

            }

            parent::saveBillingAction();
        }
```

**it's now working.**

How Can I inject when user enter wrong details?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the `saveBillingAction` is not a regular action. It does not return a full page.
It does not have a layout to it. It just returns a JSON that is evaluated by the js in charge of the checkout.

If you want to display something in the page after the `saveBillingAction` is executed you can try to add that html as a section of the returned JSON and then modify the `opcheckout.js` file so you can inject that html in the section you need.